# Search for a string in a number of files, and then rename the files with that string

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script that will search through a series of .txt files (.hl7 files to be exact, but they are just txt files) and search within those files to see if they contain a four digit number. If the file does contain that four digit number, it should then rename the file with the string added to the front of the original file name. So **test.hl7** should become **8000_test.hl7** if that file includes those 4 digits within it.

After a day of ferocious googling and digging through this website, this is the best I could muster:

```
$AccountIDs = ("8155", "8156", "8428")
$Path = "C:\Users\ThatsMe\Downloads\messages"
$Files = (Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.hl7")

for ($i = 0; $i -le $Files.Length; $i++) {
    if (Get-Content $Files[$i].FullName | Select-String -Pattern $AccountIDs[$i]) {
        Rename-Item $Files[$i].FullName -NewName (($AccountIDs[$i]) + "_" + $Files[$i].Name)
    }
}
```

I am getting some interesting results. I currently have four test files in that messages folder, **test**, **test2**, **test3**, and **skibbidybop**. The very first one, **test** gets correctly changed to **8156_test**. However, the other files aren't touched. Now, when I change the filename of **test** to **ttest**, the script completely skips over that file and then renames **test2** and **test3** to **8156_test2** (which is incorrect) and **8428_test3** respectively. **skibbidybop** is never touched.

And, of course, the error message from PowerShell:

```
Select-String : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Pattern' because it is null.
At line:6 char:61
+ if (Get-Content $Files[$i].FullName | Select-String -Pattern <<<<  $AccountIDs[$i]) {
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Select-String], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand

Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:6 char:16
+ if (Get-Content <<<<  $Files[$i].FullName | Select-String -Pattern $AccountIDs[$i]) {
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

**Updated Code**

```
$Path = "C:\Users\ThatsMe\Downloads\messages"

$pattern = '\b(8155|8156|8428)\b'
Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter '*.hl7' |
    Select-String -Pattern $pattern |
    Group-Object Path |
    ForEach-Object {
        $id       = $_.Group.Matches[0].Groups[0].Value
        $filename = $_.Group.Filename | Select-Object -First 1
        Rename-Item -Path $_.Name -NewName "${id}_${filename}" -WhatIf
    }
```

This is the error that I receive now:

```
C:\> C:\Users\ThatsMe\Downloads\messages\changename.ps1
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Users\ThatsMe\Downloads\messages\changename.ps1:8 char:38
+         $id       = $_.Group.Matches[ <<<< 0].Groups[0].Value
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

What if: Performing operation "Rename File" on Target "Item:
C:\Users\ThatsMe\Downloads\messages\test.hl7 Destination:
C:\Users\ThatsMe\Downloads\messages\_".
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Users\ThatsMe\Downloads\messages\changename.ps1:8 char:38
+         $id       = $_.Group.Matches[ <<<< 0].Groups[0].Value
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

What if: Performing operation "Rename File" on Target "Item:
C:\Users\ThatsMe\Downloads\messages\test3.hl7 Destination:
C:\Users\ThatsMe\Downloads\messages\_".
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors you get are caused by two mistakes, one of them a classic [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). PowerShell arrays are zero-based, meaning that the last index of the array is *one less than the number of its elements*:

```
[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]   → count == 3
   0    1    2      → last index == 2 == 3-1
```

Thus your `for` loop may run while `$i` is *less than* `$Files.Length` (`-lt`), *not* less or equal (`-le`):

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Files.Length; $i++) {
```

Also, you cannot use the same index variable for two different arrays (`$Files` and `$AccountIDs`) unless you made sure both arrays have the same length or at least that the second array (`$AccountIDs`) has more elements than the one used to determine the maximum index (`$Files`). If `$AccountIDs` has less elements than `$Files` your code will eventually attempt to access an index beyond the upper boundary of `$AccountIDs`. Besides, you probably want to check each file for all of the numbers from `$AccountIDs` anyway. Doing that requires a nested loop with a second index variable.

---

With that said, you're making this more complicated than it needs to be. You can simply put your IDs in a single [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) and pipe the list of files into `Select-String` to check them against that regular expression:

```
$pattern = '\b(8155|8156|8428)\b'
Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter '*.hl7' |
    Select-String -Pattern $pattern |
    Group-Object Path |
    ForEach-Object {
        $id       = $_.Group.Matches[0].Groups[0].Value
        $filename = $_.Group.Filename | Select-Object -First 1
        Rename-Item -Path $_.Name -NewName "${id}_${filename}" -WhatIf
    }
```

The regular expression `\b(8155|8156|8428)\b` matches any of the given numbers. The `\b` restrict the match to word boundaries to avoid matching numbers like 81552 or 842893 as well.

The `Group-Object` statement ensures the uniqueness of the renamed files (so that you don't attempt to rename a file more than once if more than one match is found in it).

`.Matches[0].Groups[0].Value` extracts the value of the first capturing group of the first match for each file.

The `Select-Object -First 1` ensures that even if multiple matches were found in a file you have just one string with the filename, not an array of them.

Remove the `-WhatIf` switch once you verified that the rename operation would work correctly and re-run the whole statement to actually rename the files.

---

**Edit:** For PowerShell v2 you need to adjust the group handling a little bit, because that version doesn't support [member enumeration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/06/13/new-v3-language-features/).

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter '*.hl7' |
    Select-String -Pattern $pattern |
    Group-Object Path |
    ForEach-Object {
        $id       = $_.Group | Select-Object -Expand Matches -First 1 |
                    ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[0].Value }
        $filename = $_.Group | Select-Object -Expand Filename -First 1
        Rename-Item -Path $_.Name -NewName "${id}_${filename}" -WhatIf
    }
```

Comment: Your answer put a lot into perspective and helped me understand the logical reasons of where I was going wrong. However, when I run the script I get the following error: 
`Cannot index into a null array.
At C:...changename.ps1:8 char:38
+ $id  = $_.Group.Matches[ <<<< 0].Groups[0].Value
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray`

The What If output states this happens when performing the "Rename File" operation. The script successfully finds the correct files but it doesn't seem to do much after this.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error you describe with the code you posted. Tested on an empty source folder as well as a source folder with files that produce 0, 1, and more than 1 match.

Comment: thank you for your help sir. Might it be an issue with the version of powershell I'm running? (version 2). Regardless, I will go ahead and submit this question as answered.

Comment: @sabrobby That's it. PowerShell v2 doesn't support member enumeration, which causes the problem you observed. I'd recommend upgrading to v3 or newer. If you can't do that see my updated answer for a workaround.

Comment: Yup, once I updated powershell it started to work. Thanks again!